# Spring Boot API deployed successfully but on hitting the endpoint it is returning 404

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I have deployed a SpringBoot API on Cloudfoundry PAAS, although hitting the same API on localhost returns desired result. As per my understanding, the API endpoint exists but Spring Boot controller is not accessible.

[image]

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</title><style type="text/css">body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</h1></body></html>
```

Build and deployments were successful ( Tried both via jenkins and using cf command line tool)

```
**Controller Code**
@RestController
@Validated
@RequestMapping("/someContext/v1")
public class PController {



    @GetMapping(value = "/pro")
    @RequestLogger
    @ApiOperation(value = "Get  Details", notes = "This operation is for retrieving  details.",produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
    public @ResponseBody ResponseP getDetails(
    .
    .
    .
```

Route : https://dc-cprobsdev.np3a.paas.bip.uk.xxx-intl.com/

Hitting the route with/without context root returns the same 404 result.

Comment: in your cloud foundry logs you will see route to check

Comment: Have you tried with routes

Comment: too less information, add controller code and what URL you tried to access

Comment: @Rishi -Add more info.

Comment: Yes, I took the exact endpoint URLs from Jenkins/Stratos-logs.

Comment: @Rudy Done! :) what more information would be helpful?

Comment: Did you verified into PWS console to check that the newly deployed application is showing up

Comment: Yes it is, checked with cf apps. It seems somehow starting point of the application is not accessible.I think it's related to SpringBootServletInitializer missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what was missing.
I added this class parallel to @SpringBootApplication class with name **BusinessApplication**

```
public class ServletInitializerBusinessApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(
            SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(**BusinessApplication**.class);
    }

}
```

**Question : Why it is required?**

**Answer :** SpringBootServletInitializer is an interface to run SpringApplication from a traditional WAR deployment. It binds Servlet, Filter and ServletContextInitializer beans from the application context to the server.

Nowadays we usually deploy SpringBoot Applications with JAR but in case we need a WAR Deployment, this SpringBootServletInitializer  is required.

***Following Links will help in understanding the issue more***

1. http://zetcode.com/springboot/springbootservletinitializer/
2. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-servlet-initializer